# Android Volley can't get value in separate class

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

```
public class VolleyStringRequest {
    String url;
    String body;
    String value;
    public VolleyStringRequest(String url, String body){
        this.url = url;
        this.body = body;
        value= "";
    }
    public StringRequest createStringRequest(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        Log.e("Response", response);
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("response");
                            value += values.toString();
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return body.getBytes();
            };
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        return stringRequest;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code in a seperate class to prevent code repetition but when I run this inside a fragment like this:

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://grwn.ddns.net:1337/results";
        final String body = "{\"id\":1}";
        VolleyStringRequest volleyStringRequest = new VolleyStringRequest(url, body);
        rq.add(volleyStringRequest.createStringRequest());
        volleyStringRequest.getValue();
```

And call the `getValue()` method. This method is always empty like: "". Does anyone know how I can enhance my class so this code will work? This issue is not because of a bad link or bad request. I can log the response and that does work (ofcourse inside VolleyStringRequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run:

```
VolleyStringRequest volleyStringRequest = new VolleyStringRequest(url, body);
rq.add(volleyStringRequest.createStringRequest());
volleyStringRequest.getValue();
```

But remember `createStringRequest` is async method and `value` is populated after some delay a.e. inside `public void onResponse(String response)`

So when you call `volleyStringRequest.getValue();` you get empty string

To make it work you can write some interface as:

```
  public interface RequestHandlerInterface(){
    void onResponse(String resp);
  }
```

And pass it to `VolleyStringRequest` constructor:

```
    RequestHandlerInterface rh = this;  //Your main class should implement this method
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    String url= "http://grwn.ddns.net:1337/results";
    final String body = "{\"id\":1}";
    VolleyStringRequest volleyStringRequest = new VolleyStringRequest(url, body, rh);
    rq.add(volleyStringRequest.createStringRequest());
```

Next, change your `VolleyStringRequest`:

```
public class VolleyStringRequest {
    String url;
    String body;
    String value;
    public VolleyStringRequest(String url, String body, RequestHandlerInterface rh){
        this.url = url;
        this.body = body;
        this.rh = rh;
        value= "";
    }
  //...
}
```

And once you got response from POST, call the callback as:

```
  @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
     // Do something with the response
       Log.e("Response", response);
         try{
          JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
          JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("response");
          value += values.toString();
           if(this.rh != null){
             this.rh.onResponse(value);
           }
          }  catch (JSONException ex){}
}
```

So in bottom line instead to call `volleyStringRequest.getValue();`

you have:

```
@Override
void onResponse(String resp){
     // here you go
 }
```

that will be called when you get POST response

Comment: Thanks one more question. How can I assign the resp from onResponse to a varaible? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: @SanderBakker what are you doing with `volleyStringRequest.getValue();`?

Comment: Assigning the variable? Will this work in onCreateView?

Comment: For async tasks you can use Android Handler to update main thread but its other question.